# Python/Pandas - Cumulative Sum with Interest

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Attempting to do some forecasting in pandas. I have a revenue schedule of monthly payments coming in and want to do a cumulative sum of the total - this I can esily do with `.cumsum()`. **However I would like to add a 5%pa Interest/Growth factor.**

Example df:

```
Month   Payment
2018-01  1000
2018-02  2000
2018-03   500
2018-04  1000
2018-05     0
2018-06     0
```

I'd like to output:

```
Month   Payment CumSum with Growth
2018-01  1000    1000
2018-02  2000    3005 (previous cumsum) * growth + 2000
2018-03   500    3510 (previous cumsum) * growth + 500
2018-04  1000    4510 (previous cumsum) * growth + 1000
2018-05     0    4515
2018-06     0    4520
```

- Happy to do this outside of pandas and convert back if necessary.
- The df is SMALL - speed is very much secondary concern here. Opens up raw for loop solutions perhaps?

Comment: shouldn't cumsum at 2018-08 be 3k? also it's prev*(1+ growth) not prev*growth, no?

Comment: Yes to #1 - and #2 technically true, but I was assuming we added 1 already

Comment: did the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick try:

```
def interest(data, rate):
    #turn yearly to monthly rate
    monthly = rate/12.0
    #hole output
    out = np.zeros_like(data, dtype = float)
    #initial deposit
    out[0] = data[0]
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        #t+1 = t*(1+monthly) + deposit
        out[i] = out[i - 1]*(1+monthly)+ data[i]
    return out
```

It should work as expected:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'amount':[1000,2000,500, 1000,0,0]})
interest(x.amount, 0.05)

array([1000.        , 3004.16666667, 3516.68402778, 4531.33687789,
       4550.21744822, 4569.17668759])
```